# Linq expression is not evaluated when called on empty collection

Tags: c#, linq

Consider following code:

```
class Program
{
    public static ObservableCollection<Foo> collection = new ObservableCollection<Foo>();
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Foo bar = null;
        var result1 = collection.Where(b => b.id == bar.id).FirstOrDefault();
        var result2 = collection.Where(c => c.id == bar.id).ToList();
    }
    public class Foo
    {
        public string id;
    }
}
```

This code runs smoothly. `result1` is `null`, and result2 is an empty `List<Foo>`.

If collection has elements, then exceptions are thrown, as expected. So I guess, that expressions are not evaluated if collection doesn't have elements.

In case of `FirstOrDefault` it is acceptable, since one should handle null return anyway, but in case of querying for multiple elements I find this behaviour confusing, since I can be unaware of what elements are in collection, if there is any, and pass an unitialised object in lambda by mistake, but get the somewhat "correct" result i.e. empty `List<Foo>`

Can linq expression be evaluated when collection is emty, to prevent getting unexpected result and get exception instead?

Comment: I think this boils down to the fact that you've written buggy code. You get seemingly inconsistent results because of your bug. If it were written so that `bar` was not `null` it would work fine. The error is in the `Foo bar = null;` line, and not the LINQ statements.

Comment: @Enigmativity The question isn't why the code is throwing when there are items, or even that the null value is a bug.  The question is why the bug isn't manifesting itself when the sequence is empty.  The reason he's asking this question is because *the buggy code is working* when he expects it to fail, not because the code has a bug.

Comment: @Servy - Exactly. That's why I posted this as a comment rather than an answer. I wasn't attempting to answer the question, rather I was trying to help the OP understand where the real error is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The predicate to `Where` is called *for every element in the collection* (if the entire result set is iterated).  So `Where` is absolutely executing on an empty collection, it's just not calling the predicate.  It's calling it on all zero of the items in the collection.

It is of course true that a predicate that doesn't actually work cannot be adequately tested by calling it on an empty collection.  To test that the predicate is working you'll need to have at least some of your tests have actual items in the sequence for the predicate to be called on.